# How to stream logs from multi-container Elastic Beanstalk setups to Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a multi-container Docker app (Nginx, PHP-FPM, imgproxy) and want to have all my nginx and PHP error logs in CloudWatch.

In nginx, I've set `error_log` to `/var/log/nginx/error.log warn` and then created a volume in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/html
      - ./var/log/eb-docker/containers/web:/var/log/nginx
      - socket:/var/run/php-fpm
  php:
    build:
      context: ./.docker/php-fpm
      args:
        - ENV=production
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/var/www/html
      - ./var/log/eb-docker/containers/php:/var/log/php-fpm
      - socket:/var/run/php-fpm
```

Then I've created the Cloudwatch streaming config files, but this doesn't do anything because `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/web` and `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/php` is empty on the Docker host.

I did this for my local machine too, but with `./.logs/web:/var/log/nginx` and this works fine. Is there anything that I've missed?

## Edit 1

Ok, the directory is not really empty. Looking at the host, the log folders contain the following:

[image]

But inside my Docker container it's:

[image]

I think I've configured it [as written in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html), but it doesn't work that way

## Edit 2

Oh. My. Gosh. I should remove `.` before `/var` ...

Comment: I guess you are talking about Elastic BeanStalk. Which make the ELB on your question title a bit misleading. ELB is Elastic Load Balancer

Comment: Oooh. Yes, should be EB.